# How to extend a box to the bottom within an enumerate list?

Tags: vertical-alignment

This code

```
\label{sec:issue1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
    \item test
    \item
        \resizebox{5cm}{5cm}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[thick,black] (-3,0)--(3,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {}; % x axis
                \draw[thick,black] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[left] {}; % y axis
                \draw[black,thin] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \item
\end{enumerate}
```

results in this output

[image: Output]

What do I have to change, that any box e.g. a table or in this case the tikzpicture extends to the bottom instead to the top, like this

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: The default baseline for a tikzpicture is at the bottom.  [baseline=current bounding box.north] will move the picture below the baseline instead of above. Or you could just add \par or  \newline in front.

Comment: You can also use `\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{...}` which will paritally extend above the baseline.

Answer (score 2):

The `tasks` package is eminently made just for this

Though relatively new to me the ver 1.1 year 2019 is available at `https://ctan.org/pkg/tasks?lang=en` and has got elaborate pdf documentation

The examples shown below are horizontal but enumerate is what the package is also made for

One of the examples of lists is below as a screenshot

[image]

The package also allows two column spanning as below

[image]

The package allows a combination of columns also as below

[image]

This package should suit you requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,flexisym,setspace,scrextend,siunitx,multicol,tikz,tkz-euclide,adjustbox}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,bmargin=1.4cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[counter-format ={tsk[1].}, after-skip = 1 in](3)%
 \task \adjustbox{valign=t, trim = 0pt 0pt 0pt 56.8pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(2.5,0){B}
    \tkzDrawTriangle[two angles = 60 and 60,overlay](A,B)
 \tkzGetPoint{C}
 \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}
 \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
 \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
 \tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(C)
 \tkzGetPoint{D}
 \tkzLabelPoint[above right](D){$D$}
 \tkzMarkRightAngle[color=red](C,D,A)
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](C,A,B){\small 60\si{\degree}}
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](C,B,A){\small 60\si{\degree}}
 \tkzLabelSegment[auto](C,D){$s$}
 \tkzLabelSegment[auto](A,C){$r$}
 \tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,A){18}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\task
\vadjust{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-30]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
    \tkzDrawTriangle[school,overlay](B,A)
    \tkzGetPoint{C}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](C){$C$}
    \tkzDrawAltitude(B,C)(A)
    \tkzGetPoint{D}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](D){$D$}
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[color=red](A,D,C)
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.8](C,B,A){\small 30\si{\degree}}
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.45](A,C,B){\small 60\si{\degree}}
 \tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](B,A){8}
 \tkzLabelSegment[auto,swap](C,D){$y$}
 \tkzLabelSegment[auto](A,D){$x$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```